# как разместить свой сайт ввебе

Tags: сервер, хостинг

я новичок. хочу код с компьютера переносить на Бесплатный хостинг или сервер. и чтобы сайт мой работал в вэбе и я мог давать ссылку на сайт(т.е. постоянное хранение сайта). 
это для тестов больше, и чтобы мог показать что получается, и в чем вопрос.

языки js, html,css . фронт энд в общем.

Comment: В чем заключается трудность? С чем помочь?

Comment: Слишком общий вопрос. Уточните, с чём конкретно возникли сложности, что вы уже сделали сами и что именно осталось сделать.

Comment: я хочу узнать какие есть варианты, и какими лучше пользоваться. в плане размещения своего сайта в вебе?                                                         знаю, что можно с компа или флешки свой сервер запустить. можно заплатить за хостинг платный, есть wix и пр. фигня с бесплатными хостингом, но там сайты по шаблону делаются, а не своими ручками. вот посоветуйте , чем воспользоваться , чтобы свой код выкладывать и править. чтобы потом я мог ссылку, вам , к примеру кинуть на свой сайт , и было бы круто и на код еще)

Answer (score 2):

1. Находите тот самый бесплатный хостинг/сервер, на котором собираетесь "хранить" свой сайт.
2. Этот хостинг должен поддерживать то, что Вам нужно (`языки js, html,css . фронт энд в общем`). А то ненароком он может не дать Вам доступ к БД, а она Вам вдруг ну очень может быть нужна.
3. Желательно, раз Вы уже так хотите бесплатного сыра, чтобы это хостинг предоставил какое-нибудь доменное имя n-го уровня, дабы не покупать домен.
4. Если у Вас уже есть готовый сайт, работающий локально, и более менее грамотно написанный, то его перенос заключается в обычном копировании по FTP со своего компьютера на тот самый волшебный хостинг. Если сайт работает с БД, то нужно еще и базу скопировать (но уже с помощью средств, предоставленных хостером, как то панель администрирования, ссылки на phpmyadmin и т.п.).

Самым оптимальным вариантом будет все-таки потратиться и купить VPS/VDS сервер. Придется немного поучиться работать с ним, но это лучше любого виртуального хостинга. Это как отдельный свой компьютер, на котором Вы будете почти хозяином.